# Bootstrap row dont look same when i´ll printer

Tags: printing, row

When finished my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<p><h4><center>FORMULARY</center></h4></p>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label for="inputPaterno" class="control-label">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label for="inputMaterno" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLast" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label for="inputNombre" class="control-label">Age</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAge" required>
</div>
</div>
```

and printer, see this little problem...

[image]

Sorry my english is not very good

Comment: What is the problem here ? I could not understand please make it clear

Comment: i´ll like to look similar that this [link](http://i.imgur.com/4yYAfnG.jpg) when send to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <p><h4><center>FORMULARY</center></h4></p>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-12">
    <ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
    <label for="inputPaterno" class="control-label">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" required>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label for="inputMaterno" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLast" required>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label for="inputNombre" class="control-label">Age</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAge" required>
    </li>
</ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Use list `<ul>` for that and its css class named `list-inline` or `inline-list` i don't remember proper name now but apply any one of them it will work as you want.